# php print whole page

Tags: php, echo

Quite simple question i belive. How to print the whole page into variable and then use where i need.

For instance if the code is:

```
<?php

$arr = array('hello','mate','world');
foreach ($arr as $a) {print "<p>".$a."</p>"; }

?>
```

Now if we go to that page, we can see an array output, but i would prefer to print the whole page into variable and then generate static page for instance out of that.

Maybe `file_get_content or <<<EOT`, but the page will get more complicated later so not sure what is the best option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about your exact needs but:

```
ob_start();
require('/path/to/templates/foo.php');
$template = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();

// your code

$var = ob_get_clean();

print $var;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/why_use) ,

put all HTML in a template , and insert PHP code or variables into it . in the end , using `$x=$smarty->fetch('template_name');` you put all the page in the $x variable ...

Comment: thank you, i will consider that but for now just need simple php code.

Comment: like the guys around told you . put `ob_start();` at the beginning of your script , then at the end , where you want to print everything , put `$x=ob_get_clean();` so you have all output in variable `$x`